# Kafka Java client handle connection,server issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using Kafka Java client and sometimes we have some down time in Kafka Server.
We need to send alarm to monitoring system that the Kafka server is not available.

What is the best way to make health check for Kafka server from Java client?

Answer (score 0):

If your main goal is to check whether Kafka broker cluster is up you can check via

1. Kafka broker port is available
2. Watch Zookeeper node for broker to check is any child node is available.